# Fuchsia - How to set up Dart pkgs on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, fuchsia

When I install Fuchsia for Flutter development on VS Code, I have to set up Dart pkgs. I don't have any idea about it. I'm lost. Exactly, implementing this https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/master/docs/development/languages/dart/mods.md
Any tutorials?

Comment: Are you just trying to build flutter apps, or are you trying to build and run fuchsia?

Comment: Just building Flutter apps.

Comment: Flutter is a cross-platform app development framework that targets iOS and Android with additional beta support for web and experimental support for Windows, Mac, and Linux as of this time of writing. Fuschia is an experimental new OS that Google is producing which happens to use Flutter as (currently) its primary UI driver and is very much in a "try at your own risk" stage. You absolutely do not need to build Fuschia in order to develop in Flutter - they are two completely different if somewhat related products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to install Fuchsia at all given that you are trying to build Flutter apps. While Fuchsia uses Flutter in some areas, the opposite is not true. There is no need for or reliance on Fuchsia if you would like to build flutter apps.

Open up [Flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev) and click the blue "Get Started" button in the top right. Then follow the steps and you should be on your way.

Good luck.